# Should Qt target the HyperSpace?

Tags: qt, nokia

As you may already know, [Phoenix](http://www.phoenix.com/) is developing an alternative computing environment based on top of its BIOS, called [HyperSpace](http://www.hyperspace.com/). According to its designers it should run "a collection of commonly-used browser-enabled applications designed to make the Internet browsing experience simple, fast and secure".

Although Phoenix has declared in its FAQ that you will *not* be able to install/run your own applications on top of the HyperSpace, in [a recent interview](http://www.technologyreview.com/computing/22643/page1/) on MIT's Technology Review said that they are planning to open in June an iTunes-styled store to sell applications.

I'm guessing they are probably up to Apple's business model of providing secure applications via a centralized service thus sooner or later a developer toolkit shall arrive.

Since Qt has an impressive record of cross-platform capabilities, do you believe that Nokia should make an alliance with Phoenix to port the Qt toolkit to the coming HyperSpace application developers? If it's not Qt what should the ideal developing platform for HyperSpace be?

Comment: Kensai, this is an interesting topic, but is there a programming question in there anywhere?

Comment: I 2nd Jeff.  While an interesting topic, it seems more about marketing and business strategy and speculation than pure bit-twiddling API-inhaling protocol-twisting programming.  This sort of stuff goes best in a regular open tech/business forum.

Or, how about a new stackoverflow-style site for this kind of stuff?   In the same vein as "serverfault.com", and - as someone proposed for photography - "lensflare",  how about a www.plummetingsales.com for marketing, product development, strategic aliances and such?

Comment: Well, you don't have to necessarily see it as a "marketing/business strategy". Just explain to me if there are technical reasons behind choosing Qt for HyperSpace which are better than other solutions/toolkits.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that this is basically a dual boot machine.

- one boot goes to a version of windows that QT supports (or will presumably support).
- one goes to a web browser and will only run web applications or widgets.

If your asking whether QT should allow you to target the second environment, then it all depends on whether that is even remotely compatible with the QT technological choice of including a Webkit engine.

There could also be a licensing issue.

I am not convinced the Hyperspace product is aimed at desktop developers the way QT is. I think it's aimed at web applications developers.

Edit: What you seem to wonder is whether Nokia sees a commercial interest in supporting Hyperspace and whether they have the resources to do it. Unfortunately, I suspect only the head of QT development at Nokia can truly answer that.

Comment: According to the new Nokia masterplan of October 2008, the Internet is fair play for the Qt as well. So I guess creating low footprint web applications to run on the HyperSpace with the help of the Qt toolkit might be indeed possible.

The question is: is HyperSpace an interesting enough solution to target for Qt or some other toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

"I am not convinced the Hyperspace product is aimed at desktop developers the way QT is"
Qt is aimed at embedded mobile phone apps, they are now owned by Nokia, if Qt happens to run on desktops that is just a nice bonus for Nokia.

Given it's, small size, no external dependencies and 'easy to port'-ness I would have thought Qt was a good start for a bios-os desktop.

Comment: I dont think Nokia's current vision or TrollTech's past for QT to be only for "embedded mobile phone apps". If that would be the case, people at KDE camp would be really terrified.

Comment: No, I was just making the point that embedded is a big part of Qt that most of us desktop programmers never think of